# ASP.NET buttons became shorter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I haven't changed anything in .css file, but every button in my project (in masterpage and .aspx files became shorter (~25px length)). I remember that i had something like this long time ago, but can't remember the solution. Could anyone tell me what's the cause of it and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your css and button code??

Comment: I have 5+ types of buttons and buttons without cssclass, but they are now same size. I haven't changed anything in css file.

Answer (score 2):

Use Developer Tools on IE or Firebug on Firefox (hit F12) and trace the css.
Here is an example of how you can do that:

[image: Trace CSS styles.]

Comment: I have checked, the each type of buttons has its own cssclass as it should be, but there is nothing saying that button sizes are limited.

Comment: Maybe you're applying a javascript/css selector badly.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem is you can change the length of buttons by marking them as **"!important"** this will apply the new CSS to all the buttons and whatsoever length is applied earlier will get diminished.

for e.g.:

```
.example { font-size: 14px !important; }
```

Accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: it didn't helped me, Anubhav

Comment: Then you should search your Entire Solution for "25px", this will tell you from where you are getting this CSS